# What is $\mathrm{Sym}(V)$, where $V$ is a vector space

Tags: notation, vector-spaces

What is $\mathrm{Sym}^n(V)$, where $V$ is a vector space? (I've found a problem list and have some problems on notations)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra

Answer (score 8):

$\operatorname{Sym}(V)$ is the symmetric algebra over $V$, which is a vector space over the ground field $\mathbb K$. It is defined as the quotient

$$\operatorname{Sym}(V):=T(V)/(R),$$

where $T(V)=\mathbb K\oplus V\oplus (V\otimes V)\oplus \dots \oplus V^{\otimes n}\oplus\dots$ is the tensor algebra over $V$ and $(R)$ denotes the 2-sided ideal in $T(V)$ generated by the relations

$$v_1\otimes v_2-v_2\otimes v_1,$$

for all $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $V$. Let us describe such definition in some detail.

- On $T(V)$

The vector space $T(V)$ is a unital associative algebra with composition $\star$ given by concatenation of tensors, i.e.

$$(v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n)\star (w_1\otimes\dots\otimes w_r):= v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n \otimes w_1\otimes\dots\otimes w_r,  $$

for all $v_1,\dots w_r\in V$. Associativity of $\star$ follows from associativity of $\otimes$. We can safely write $\star=\otimes$, then. The unit for such product is given by the unit $1$ in the ground field $\mathbb K$. In a more compact form

$$T(V)=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}V^{\otimes n},$$

where $V^{\otimes 0}:=\mathbb K$. The index $n$ is called the "weight".

- Remark 0

If $V$ is a graded vector field, then the weight $n$ is not the correct grading on $T(V)$. This is a common source of (little) confusion in graded algebra.

- Remark 1

If you are interested in applications in homological algebra/algebraic topology, then you probably need to consider that the tensor algebra is an **augmented** unital associative algebra, but let us skip that fact here.

- Remark 2

There exists a "dual" (in some sense) construction on the tensor algebra endowing it with an associative counital coaugmented coalgebra structure, but this is not relevant here. It is important in modern "quantum" algebra, though.

- On $(R)$: definition

What is $(R)$? By definition we have

$$(R)=T(V)\otimes \mathbf{R} \otimes T(V), $$

where the vector space $\mathbf{R}$ is given by

$$\mathbf{R}:=\operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb K}(v_1\otimes v_2-v_2\otimes v_1,~~\forall v_1,v_2\in V). $$

Now it is clear that $(R)$ is a two-sided ideal in $T(V)$ (once again, the product in the tensor algebra is the "concatenation").

- On $(R)$: some explicit formulae.

Why do we introduce such ideal $(R)$?
 The effect of introducing the ideal is to "force" tensors  to be symmetric...in the symmetric algebra (not in the tensor algebra!): let us briefly discuss it.
We decompose the symmetric algebra $\operatorname{Sym}(V):=T(V)/(R)$ w.r.t. the weight $n$, i.e.

$$\operatorname{Sym}(V):=T(V)/(R)=\mathbb K\oplus V\oplus \left(V^{\otimes 2}/\mathbf{R}\right) \oplus \left( V^{\otimes 3}/(V\otimes \mathbf{R} \oplus \mathbf{R}\otimes V) \right)\oplus\dots.   $$

Note that $(R)$ has no contributions in weight $n=0$ and $n=1$ because $\mathbf{R}\subset V\otimes V$: in other words, the effect of "symmetrizing" tensors is felt in the components of $T(V)$ with weight $\geq 2$ (which is what the above decomposition says).
The quotient in weight $n=3$ is obtained by observing that the restriction to weight $n=3$ of the two sided ideal $T(V)\otimes \mathbf{R} \otimes T(V)$ is

$$\left[T(V)\otimes \mathbf{R} \otimes T(V)\right]|_{n=3}=[(\mathbb K\oplus V\oplus (V\otimes V)\oplus \dots )\otimes \mathbf{R} \otimes (\mathbb K\oplus V\oplus (V\otimes V)\oplus \dots )]|_{n=3}= (V\otimes \mathbf{R}\otimes\mathbb K) \oplus (\mathbb K \otimes \mathbf{R}\otimes V )\simeq V\otimes \mathbf{R} \oplus \mathbf{R}\otimes V,$$

as deduced above. For higher weights the procedure is similar (you can find a general formula with little work).

As $(R)$ is an ideal, denoting by

$$v_1\cdot\cdots\cdot v_n:= p(v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n) $$

the image of any $v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n\in T(V)$ under the projection map

$$T(v)\twoheadrightarrow\operatorname{Sym}(V),$$

then the product $(v_1\cdot\cdots\cdot v_n)\cdot (w_1\cdot\cdots\cdot w_r):=p(v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n\otimes w_1\otimes\cdots\otimes w_r )$ is well defined (check it!) and makes the symmetric algebra into an associative unital algebra.

By definition of symmetric algebra for $v_1\otimes v_2$ and $v_2\otimes v_1$ in $V^{\otimes 2}\subset T(V)$ we have

$$v_1\cdot v_2=v_2\cdot v_1$$

in $\operatorname{Sym}(V),$ because $v_1\cdot v_2-v_2\cdot v_1\in (R)$, by definition of $(R)$. With tensors in higher weights the analysis is similar (try the case $n=3$).

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is a VERY complete answer. (+1)