# Algebra "A/I": what does it mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, quotient-spaces

I have an Algebra $A$ and an Ideal $I \subset A$.

What is the algebra $A/I$ ?

I've seen it several times but I can't find the definition...

Maybe is it the subspace of $A$ that is $A \ominus I$ ?

Comment: It is called the quotient.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring

Comment: Ah! It's about the rings! I had found that definition but I thought that was not my case because the text never mentions explicitely "rings". Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you wanna have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444094/what-is-mathrmsymv-where-v-is-a-vector-space/444132#444132, last part. You find the explicit construction of an example of quotient ring.

Comment: But algebras are in particular also rings. Which text is this that discusses algebras and not rings?